# How do i execute native react from a different root file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried running expo from a file other than App.js but anytime i tried, the default App.js was executed instead of the secondary file.

Comment: check the docs on expo https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your package.json. Inside the config object you'll find the ''main'' key, that's the key responsible for saying what the first file to run is!

Usually you'll find another path that leads to `node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` (see, it's **expo**, not node_modules/@expo).

Inside  `node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js` you'll see an import like this: `import App from '../../App';`
That's where you can choose any other file to be the first to run!

More info at https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/